# PHP Variables and its way to display with some discipline

Tags: php, database, variables, shortcut

here is my variables

```
$error=[];

$dbname=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbname"]));
$dbusername=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbusername"]));
$dbpassword=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbpassword"]));
$dbhost=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbhost"]));;
$debugging=$_POST["debugging"];

...  // i got such variables many some are not belong to post as well
```

i want to display error like this

```
if(empty($dbname){
echo $error['$dberro']="Hey you have missed the database name";
}
if(empty($dbusername){
echo $error['$dbusernameerror']="Hey you have missed the database user name";
}
....   // i have such code many
```

i have such 40 variables and how do i do so very easily ..and i display on static page or some other php page like this

```
if (isset($error[$dberror])){
echo "$error[$dberror]";
}
... //i have such many
```

isn't the code so much bulky probably there is better idea than this

can i get those idea

Comment: A foreach loop should be an easier/more compact way to display your errors

Comment: I hope now you understand why you should use a PHP Framework ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux PHP Framework for a single piece of script? That's like building a skyscraper to open a coffee shop. Surely a basic foreach loop as ChrisWillard mentioned is the way to go

Comment: frame work...?? why to use ??

Comment: Framework why to use... Hard to read ! And why a single piece of script ? He defines db connection, so surely not a single PHP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a first array to store variable and its description
and another one to store datas :

```
<?php
$error=[];
//data associate var and its description
$data[
    'dbname'=>'database name',
    'dbusername'=>'database user name',
    'dbpassword'=>'database password',
    'dbhost'=>'database host',
    'debugging'=>'debugging'
    ];

//values store the values in an array
$values['dbname']=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbname"]));
$values['dbusername']=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbusername"]));
$values['dbpassword']=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbpassword"]));
$values['dbhost']=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbhost"]));;
$values['debugging']=$_POST["debugging"];

//test values
foreach($data as $var=>$description){
    if(empty($values[$var]){
        echo $error[$var]="Hey you have missed the ".$description;
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer this is what exactly i was searching XD

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and loop through it to check.. Something like this:

```
$db_array = array(
'dbname' => htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbname"])),
'dbusername' => htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbusername"])),
etc..
etc..
);

foreach($db_array as $key => $value) {
  if(empty($value)) {
    echo "Hey you have missed: $key";
  }
}
```

Edit: Corrected as per jtmanteos comment

Comment: I don't think you want to check `empty($key)` because it will never be empty. I think you want `empty($value)`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @jtmanteo that one slipped past me. :/

Comment: But it says "Hey you missed dbname" not database name isn't it??

Comment: @user3689984; that was just an example of how you could do it. You'd need to work it into your script, it wont be as easy as copy/paste but should give you an idea of how you could handle it.

Comment: ahh yes but i said i want to display message like this * You missed the database name *  is quuestion not clear ?

Comment: It's a little unclear.
You have already set all the variables and recorded any errors into array, or not? If you're looking to just loop the error array, that's easy. If you're looking for a way to condense everything, then my answer should give you an idea of one way you could go about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $$key = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["dbname"]));
        if(empty($$key)) {
            echo "Hey you have missed: $key";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This solution assumes that your submission form html has inputs named after all the keys you are looking for and that all the inputs have the 'value' attribute. If not, then the keys won't even show up in your post array to begin with.